# Proving that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^\alpha}$ is not the Fourier Series of a Riemann Integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, riemann-integration

In Stein and Shakarchi's *Fourier Analysis* book, I am working Problem 1 of Chapter 3, where we are walked through a proof that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^\alpha}$ is not the Fourier Series of any function $f\in L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ $\hspace{2mm}\forall 0<\alpha<1$, despite the fact that the sum converges pointwise everywhere on the interval.
In parts (a) and (b), we introduce the conjugate Dirichlet Kernel
$$\tilde{D}_N (x) = \sum_{|n|\leq N} \text{sgn}(n) e^{inx}$$

We then show that if $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[-\pi,\pi]$, then $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x) \tilde{D}_N (x)|dx \leq \mathcal{O}(\text{log}(N))$.

Part (c) asks us to consider the function $g=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^\alpha}$, and show that if we assume it is the Fourier Series of some Riemann integrable function $f$, this leads to the contradiction that
$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^\alpha} = \mathcal{O}(\text{log}(N))$.

The book clearly wants me to *plug in* the function we are given to part (b), and this is where I have my questions.

(1) We know g converges pointwise on $[-\pi,\pi]$, but is it integrable? I assume it is, but how do we know this?

(2) If g is integrable, we can take its Fourier series. Is the Fourier Series of g also $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^\alpha}$? How could we show this?

Comment: convergence of $g$ follows from Dirrichlet's test of convergence.

Comment: In my copy of the book, the problem asks to show that that series $g$ is not the Fourier series of a Riemann integrable function, (not of an $L^2$ function as you say). In fact, if $\alpha > 1/2$, then Parseval's theorem shows that $g$ is in $L^2$. I think you have to assume that $g$ is integrable and obtain a contradiction.